# Javascript TypeError: document.routeEvent is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, syntax-error

I am work on a old page that have javascript. And have funtion that not work whit new browser like Mozilla, chrome and safari. But all the page are continue work on IE 11.`document.routeEvent(e);` But I dont know wat are the problem. I user FireBug and bring me the error *Javascript TypeError: document.routeEvent is not a function*

I will thanks you all your help.

```js
function markClick(e) {
  if (isIE || isOpera6) {
    winX=event.screenX;
    winY=event.screenY;
  }
  else if (isN4 || isN6) {
    winX=e.screenX;
    winY=e.screenY;

    document.routeEvent(e);
  }

  if (isN4 || isN6) { 
    document.routeEvent(e); 
  } 
  else { 
    event.cancelBubble=false; 
  } 

  return true;
}
```

Comment: `document.routeEvent` is deprecated. As the error itself suggests your browser doesn't support this method

Comment: try replacing document with window

Comment: If you check out the mdn article on routeEvent you will see it's obsolete for Obsolete since Gecko 24 (Firefox 24 / Thunderbird 24 / SeaMonkey 2.21): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/routeEvent

Answer (score 0):

Document.routeEvent has been deprecated and its support has been removed from browsers from 2008, check this [bug listing](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=673919#c33).

> As per this changeset,
>   * Still available: captureEvents, releaseEvents
>   * Removed: routeEvent, enableExternalCapture, disableExternalCapture so the summary should be corrected here.

Comment: Then should replace the routeEvent by enableExternalCapture ?

Comment: @Lord_Dath_Angel No that is also deprecated

Comment: In this case I don't have form to update this line code? the only way is re-program it whit new code?

Comment: @Lord_Dath_Angel what are you trying to do with routeEvent here?

Comment: Thanks you for your help. I do not understand the syntax of javascript. this is a new language to me. but I think that this for compare a period of time. get date x to compare date y. this code come from a funtion table of calendar.